# redis executing too many 'info' commands

Tags: redis, redis-cli, redis-commands

When I monitor the Redis using `monitor` command I observe there are lots of `info` command is being executed. Is this executed by Redis server itself or by the client applications?

The problem is, when I check the output of the `client list` command on the server, there are lots of open connection objects on `info` command which is causing the server to crash with below error.

`ReplyError: Ready check failed: ERR max number of clients reached`

```
id=3066244 addr=127.0.0.1:47496 fd=440 name= age=101 idle=101 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=info
id=3066245 addr=127.0.0.1:47498 fd=441 name= age=101 idle=100 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=info
id=3066246 addr=127.0.0.1:47500 fd=442 name= age=101 idle=101 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=info
id=3066247 addr=127.0.0.1:47502 fd=443 name= age=101 idle=100 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=info
id=3066248 addr=127.0.0.1:47504 fd=444 name= age=101 idle=101 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=info
id=3066249 addr=127.0.0.1:47506 fd=445 name= age=101 idle=100 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=info
id=3066250 addr=127.0.0.1:47508 fd=446 name= age=101 idle=101 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=info
id=3066251 addr=127.0.0.1:47510 fd=447 name= age=101 idle=101 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=info
id=3066252 addr=127.0.0.1:47512 fd=448 name= age=101 idle=100 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=info
id=3066253 addr=127.0.0.1:47514 fd=449 name= age=101 idle=100 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=info
id=3066254 addr=127.0.0.1:47516 fd=450 name= age=101 idle=100 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=info
id=3066255 addr=127.0.0.1:47518 fd=451 name= age=101 idle=100 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=info
id=3066256 addr=127.0.0.1:47520 fd=452 name= age=101 idle=100 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=info
id=3066257 addr=127.0.0.1:47522 fd=454 name= age=101 idle=100 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=info
```

Comment: Seems like you are opening multiple Unix socket connections until you reach Redis limit which is 128 by default.

Comment: in the client application, I am opening and closing the connection whenever it is required, but does every open connection makes a ```info``` call on the Redis?